# PHP preg_replace alway's overwrite my read file

Tags: php

I have a TEXT file bla.txt

REGION_NAME = 'bla_2'

hello

hi

goodbye

my script##

```
<?php
   $file = 'bla.txt';
   $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
   $fh = fopen($file, "w");
   $file_contents = preg_replace("/(REGION_NAME =) ('')/", "$1 'us-east-A'", "REGION_NAME = ''");
   fwrite($fh, $file_contents);
   fclose($fh);
?>
```

When I run it, It adds the correct text but then overwrites the bla.txt file
so and I loose the other words.

NOTE:### If I use str_replace works fine but once bla_2 changes then we can't use the script again...

Any Idea...?

```
$file_contents = str_replace('bla_2','bar',$file_contents);
```

Comment: fopen($file,'w') opens the file for writing at the beginning of the file.  fopen($file,'a') opens the file for writing at the end of the file, so it shouldn't overwrite your file.  See the fopen manual.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the code you are overwriting the initial value of `$file_contents`, not replacing against the data in `$file_contents`. What you need to do is: `$file_contents = preg_replace("/(REGION_NAME =) ('')/", "$1 'us-east-A'", $file_contents);`. And as a disclaimer I didn't actually run your code but you weren't passing in the correct subject for the function from what I see.

And I think what you want for regex is something along the lines of `preg_replace("REGION_NAME = '(.*)'", 'us-east-A', $file_contents)`

Comment: so now file does not get over written but the text in line is not getting changes.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the regex? I ask because im not the best at regex but that doesnt look right to me.

Comment: Here is my actual file i'm trying to open change and save

Comment: import boto.vpc 
import boto.ec2
import VPCConnection
import time
#boto.set_stream_logger('boto')

#Connect with AWS region

REGION_NAME = 'bla_2'

#Connect with your Region
conn = boto.vpc.connect_to_region(REGION_NAME)


vpc = conn.create_vpc('10.10.0.0/16')
print vpc

Comment: I'm trying to replace the text after REGION_NAME = 'bla_2"      so... only changing 'bla_2' in the file and would then run script again to replace after REGION_NAME =   '  '     so str_replace will not work as bla_2 will always be different next time file is open.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: i got it with $file_contents = preg_replace("/(REGION_NAME =) (.*)/", "$1 'us-east-b'", $file_contents);

Comment: $file_contents = preg_replace("/(REGION_NAME =) (.*)/", $_POST['rname'], $file_contents);